# Export And Make String Valid for 7 Days in MYSQL Database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

i have got the following code which creates a random string:

```
<form name="randform">
<input type="button" value="Create Random String" onClick="randomString();">&nbsp;
<div id="xyz"></div>
</form>



  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstringy = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstringy += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = ""+randomstringy;}
```

Now i want to export this string to a database in MySQL and make it valid for 7 days.
The Goal would be, that the user generates a code, which would get stores in a DB, then the user tries to log in on another page using this code (which is then only possible if its still valid)

how would i proceed to do this using this code? i managed to export some other form input on another page to a database but thats the extent of my knowledge.

Comment: Why don't you add a expiry coloumn in your table and set the expiry time for it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no specific TTL function for the records in mysql, however there is an [`Event Scheduler`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html) which you can write queries to run periodically. But I think it would not be suitable for you, if you are expecting.

If I am you, then this is how I am going to solve this.

1. Create a separate table `Session_Data`. Have columns `user_id`, `session_id`, `session_created_at`.
2. The column `session_id` (type of `VARCHAR(512)`) is for storing generated code.
3. The column `session_created_at` (type of `TIMESTAMP`) to store when this code has been generated.
4. When you post this form data, the backend service must store/update this generated hash in the database.

   `INSERT INTO Session_Data (user_id, session_id, session_created_at) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())`
5. And whenever a user comes asking for a page, check this table to fetch the code associated with the user and validate the `session_created_at` and current time difference is larger than 7 days. This will return a record if a code is there generated within last 7 days, otherwise will return none. Based on that you can allow/deny page viewing.

   `SELECT * FROM Session_Data WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, session_created_at, NOW()) <= 100080 WHERE user_id = ?`

Alternatively, you can add those two columns into the `User` table as well. But it is better you keep these information in a separate table.